# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header but no access to API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm trying to use the UK Parliament API but I'm hitting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://findyourmp.parliament.uk/api/search?q=london&f=js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I know what it means, but there's no JSONP option and I can't edit Parliament's API. How can I get around this? Could I route the request through a PHP file on my server that I can allow access to or would that not solve the problem?

Here's my code:

```
var search_term = $('#input').val();
var url = 'http://findyourmp.parliament.uk/api/search?q=' + search_term + '&f=js';

$.getJSON(url, function(jd) {
    $('#div').html('<p>Constituency: ' + jd.constituency_name + '</p>');
});
```

**EDIT**

[API here.](http://findyourmp.parliament.uk/api)

Comment: I don't believe routing it through PHP would make a difference. Not sure though. For security reasons, I don't think you're supposed to be able to get around this.

Comment: @War10ck Thanks for your reply. If you're not supposed to get around this, what's the point in having an API?

Comment: @Sebastian is it a public api?

Comment: @DanielA.White yep, I've just added a link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Yes, you can get the contents from the API with a serverside language, like PHP. The missing header is only to circumvent javascripts same-origin policy, and does not matter when you're using the server to contact the API.

Answer (score 1):

yes using serverside "proxy" would solve the problem, as the Access-Control-Allow_Origin is for client-side calls

simple php snippet

```
$search_term = "find";
$url = "http://findyourmp.parliament.uk/api/search?q=".$search_term."&f=js";
return file_get_contents($url);
```