# Allow access to API build in XAMPP from WAMP

Tags: api, xampp, wamp

I built an api in my XAMPP Server, with the database and so on (working fine). But now I am currently using WAMPP to make another web application. I reckon it is possible to link them eachother, so I don't need to make the whole API rest again.

The thing is I want to attack that database via that API.

Simply adding the url with the server ON is not working:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/slim/api.php/books. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3002' is therefore not allowed access.

I have a look around and I just found [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938277/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-but-no-access-to-api) but it is not working, or I am not doing it in the right way.

Could it be slim permissions? I have tried but nothing happened yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was **SOLVED** by adding this code at the beggining of the api.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```